# Who can provide the paper "Theoria interpolationis methodo nova tractata"?

Tags: reference-request, algorithms, fourier-analysis, math-history, fast-fourier-transform

Recently, I'm learning FFT and I want to read this original paper("Theoria interpolationis methodo nova tractata", by Carl Friedrich Gauss. ). But I can't get a valid url from Internet.

Would someone give me a valid download url about this paper(or just send me that file via any viable method)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: A cursory search suggests the "*original paper*" was an unpublished manuscript. It appears to be included in Gauss' Werke Band III (Göttingen, 1876) starting at p. 265 [here](https://archive.org/details/werkecarlf03gausrich/page/n277/mode/2up?view=theater).

Comment: @dxiv  Thanks for your answer, maybe you can ask that as a answer and I select that as the best answer.

Comment: Do you read Latin?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The original paper appears to have been an unpublished manuscript, which was later included in C.F. Gauss' Werke Band III (Göttingen, 1876) starting at p. 265, available on [archive.org](https://archive.org/details/werkecarlf03gausrich/page/n277/mode/2up?view=theater).

[image]

A digitized version is available on [hathitrust.org](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=hvd.32044017967191&view=1up&seq=279).

[image]